# Calculating the volume and the surface area of a special ellipse

Tags: integration, mathematical-modeling

I'm a high school student trying to model an egg-shaped object. I have found this formula describing my object:
$$\frac{x^2}{10+3x}+\frac{y^2}{4}=0.5$$

The next step is to calculate the volume and surface area, and the only method I know is to integrate it. However, the equation is both over and under x-axis, so I can't use the solid of revolution formula. If I rotate it for only 180 degrees like this:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\pi}{2}y^2 \;\mathrm{dx}$$
will it give me the volume of the thing? If it doesn't work like that, what are the methods I could use?

Comment: I dont understand what you call "volume". The equation you have is a "egg-shape" in the $xy$-plane, but if you wish think it in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then it is a cylinder (because the $z$ variable is free) and for that the "volume" will be $\infty$.

You want to calculate the area of the plane "egg-shape"??

Comment: Ah, that's a question I didn't consider. Basically I want to calculate the volume of an egg, and the formula I found fits quite perfectly to the cross section area of the egg. Do you think there is any ways where I can use that function to calculate its volume? Suppose the z-axis has the same magnitude as the minor axis on xy plane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the given equation describes the $xy$-plane cross-section of a solid of revolution whose axis of symmetry is the $x$-axis, then the equation for the surface will be given by $$\frac{x^2}{10+3x} + \frac{y^2 + z^2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}. \tag{1}$$

The volume of interest may be computed via the method of disks:

$$V = \int_{x=(3-\sqrt{89})/4}^{(3+\sqrt{89})/4} \pi \frac{20 + 6x - 4x^2}{10 + 3x} \, dx. \tag{2}$$

I leave the computation of the antiderivative and the subsequent volume as an exercise for the reader; it is not difficult.

The surface area is given by

$$S = 2\pi \int_{x=(3-\sqrt{89})/4}^{(3+\sqrt{89})/4} f(x) \sqrt{1 + (f'(x))^2} \, dx, \\ f(x) = \sqrt{\frac{20+6x-4x^2}{10+3x}}, \tag{3}$$ which is understandably quite messy to write out explicitly and does not admit an elementary closed form solution.  Numeric integration is feasible, however.